# Setting a Chart Title on a template

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart template set up and I need to change the title but cannot find our the title is looking up the formula in the title is ='Chart Titles'!%$A$3:$D$3, I cannot find where this is pointing to change the name that it is returning.

Tried looking for the place where this is located

Comment: Are you sure there's a % sign in there?

Answer (score 1):

'Chart Titles' is the name of a sheet. If you can't see it, it's probably hidden. Right-click on any other sheet name at the bottom and choose "unhide..." then unhide the sheet from there.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about a hidden sheet sorted now thanks again